# Test React Component with Jest and Enzyme, which are returned by a map function

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

i'm using Jest and Enzyme to test React components, but i found difficulties on testing a simple stateless component which consist on the result of a map javascript function.

**MovieCard.js** Component:

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

const MovieCard = ({ resultsForSubmit }) =>
  (
    resultsForSubmit.map(r => (
      <article className="card" key={r.imdbID}>
        <a href={r.Poster}>
          <picture className="thumbnail">
            <img src={(r.Poster !== "N/A")? r.Poster : "src/assets/not-found.png"} alt={r.Title} />
          </picture>
        </a>
        <div className="card-content clearfix">
          <div className="review">
            <h2>{r.Title}</h2>
            <p>{r.Type}</p>
          </div>
          <div className="reviewer">
          </div>
        </div>
      </article>
    )
    )
  )

export default MovieCard;

MovieCard.propTypes = {
  resultsForSubmit: PropTypes.array,
}
```

**MovieCard.test.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { mount  } from 'enzyme'
import MovieCard from './MovieCard';

describe('<MovieCard /><MovieCard />', () => {
    const data = [
        { imdbId: '2', Poster: 'poster2', Title: 'title2', Type: 'type2' }
    ];

    it('renders 2 <MovieCard /> components', () => {
        mount(<MovieCard data={ data } />);
    });
})
```

**when i run the test, this error is shown :**

```
**<MovieCard /><MovieCard /> › renders 2 <MovieCard /> components

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

      4 | const MovieCard = ({ resultsForSubmit }) =>
      5 |   (
    > 6 |     resultsForSubmit.map(r => (
        |                      ^
      7 |       <article className="card" key={r.imdbID}>
      8 |         <a href={r.Poster}>
      9 |           <picture className="thumbnail">**
```

For now i just want to test if the component is rendered, but i'm open to suggestion for using other testing functions on it.

Comment: your component is trying to iterate through prop with name of `resultsForSubmit` while you are passing `data` and not passing `resultsForSubmit `. so at first you have to use appropriate prop name. also maybe you may enhance render part to check if `resultsForSubmit` exists at all to avoid unrecoverable error and to see some message instead

Comment: you are right, i was sending data as prop, and not resultsForSubmit, thank you

Answer (score 0):

`<MovieCard />` expects a prop `resultsForSubmit` and you are passing down `data` on your test.

Try something like this instead:

**MovieCard.test.js**

```
describe('<MovieCard />', () => {
  const resultsForSubmit = [
    { imdbId: '1', Poster: 'poster1', Title: 'title1', Type: 'type1' },
    { imdbId: '2', Poster: 'poster2', Title: 'title2', Type: 'type2' }
  ];
  let movieCard; 

  beforeEach(() => {
    movieCard = shallow(<MovieCard resultsForSubmit={resultsForSubmit} />);
  });

  it('renders 2 articles', () => {
    expect(movieCard.find('article').length).toBe(2);
  });
})
```

Comment: it works, thank you. I was passing data as props not resultsForSubmit.